# Dynamically change line in console

Tags: python

I am currently building a little "chat bot" program, the concept being that it should be able to asynchronously process information and output at any time.  Additionally, the user can enter input at any time.

I've got the basic mechanics down, but I'm having trouble getting it to look nice in the console.  I want it to work like the following:

1. Every time the bot outputs, it should appear on a new console line.
2. The user text input line should always stay at the very bottom of the console, and (of course) you should be able to see what you are typing.
3. When the user sends the input, the entered text should appear as a new line in the console, and a new input line will be created.

This is the code I'm currently using, but it's quite buggy:

```
def writeToConsole(line,static=False):
  if static:
      sys.stdout.write("\r"+line)
  else:
      print("\r"+line)
```

When "static" is False, I want a new line to be written.  If it is True, I want the input line to read as "line".  What is actually happening is all the static=False lines kind of write over the static=True lines, but any characters past the length of the new line are still there.

Any help in achieving the effect I am looking for would be much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to divide a text console into different regions and handle I/O differently for each.  On Linux you would use something like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/curses.html).  On Windows you'll have to use [unicurses](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UniCurses) or something similar.  You can certainly write your program without it, by buffering all of the lines of the terminal, updating the buffer the way you want, and rewriting the screen each time, but investing the time in learning a curses API will let you focus on your app logic, not the console.

Comment: @robert_x44 Yeah, I was thinking about just redrawing the entire console, but that's functionality I would rather not have to resort to because it'd just get in the way of progress.  I had heard of curses, but wasn't really sure what exactly their function was...thanks for this, I'll take a look.